# Is there any difference between 'mirroring a repo' and 'importing a repo' in github?

Tags: git, github, repo

What difference does it make if we mirror a repository from an organization we are in, or import a repository while creating a new one. Are there any specific advantages?

Answer (score 1):

From Github docs [Mirroring a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository) and [Importing a Git repository using the command line](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/importing-a-git-repository-using-the-command-line), we can see the commands are the same, `git clone --bare` and `git push --mirror`. So I think they are the same thing in Github.

But when it comes to Git, `mirror` reminds me of `git clone --mirror` and `git push --mirror`. There are [differences](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone/en#Documentation/git-clone.txt---mirror) between `--mirror` and `--bare`. If you want to preserve all refs in the server repository, use `git clone --mirror`. If you want to preserve only branches and tags, use `git clone --bare`. As to `all refs`, they are builtin types of refs like branches, tags, notes, etc. The hosting service may use some special customized refs that cannot be fetched by `git clone --mirror`.